# why firefox file download is running inside Tomcat?

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, tomcat, jsf-2, tomcat7

when i want to run my xhtml file, firefox file download is running inside Tomcat.
what shall i do? please help me. before this page, it worked well. but now firefox file download is running inside the eclipse. i don't know what i should do.
[image]

personel.xhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui"
>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>اطلاعات پرسنلی</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>اضافه کردن پرسنل جدید</h1>
        <h:form>

            <h:panelGrid columns="6" dir="rtl">
              شماره پرسنلی : 
                <h:inputText id="name" value="#{personelMB.personel_id}" 
                    size="20" required="true"
                    label="id" >
                </h:inputText>
                نام : 
                <h:inputText id="name" value="#{personelMB.pname}" 
                    size="20" required="true"
                    label="Name" >
                </h:inputText>

                 نام خانوادگی: 
                <h:inputText id="family" value="#{personelMB.pfamily}" 
                    size="20" required="true"
                    label="family" >
                </h:inputText> 

                آدرس : 
                <h:inputTextarea id="address" value="#{personelMB.paddress}" 
                    cols="30" rows="10" required="true"
                    label="Address" >
                </h:inputTextarea>


          تلفن:  
                <h:inputText id="tel" value="#{personelMB.pphone}" 
                    size="20" required="true"
                    label="tel" >
                </h:inputText> 
            </h:panelGrid>

            <h:commandButton value="درج اطلاعات" action="#{personelMB.addPersonel()}" />

        </h:form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does it mean that "firefox browser is running inside Tomcat" ?

Comment: @PeterGwiazda, the picture message i have added above, is appeared when i run my xhtml file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i cleaned the tomcat directory and it solved.